# Hide the `terminal` launcher icon for a terminal app launched from Unity dash/launcher

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal, 16.10

I have created a Unity Dash entry for `neovim` (using `alacarte`), which runs the command `gnome-terminal -e nvim`, and have locked it to my launcher.

[image: Screenshot showing launcher icon for a terminal application]

When I click it, a new terminal window appears, and *a new icon appears in the launcher*, as shown below:

[image: Screenshot showing separate terminal icon for a application launched from launcher]

I guess it is working as expected, but is there a way I can hide the `gnome-terminal` launcher icon, and have the actual neovim launcher be active instead?

Comment: Have you tried simply moving the terminals launcher from it folder `sudo mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop ~/` this will move the launcher to your home, then when you run the custom launcher, the normal one won't show.

Comment: @MarkKirby: Doing that simply hides/removes `gnome-terminal` from the list of applications available in the dash. Launching `neovim` from my launcher icon still shows the terminal icon, exactly as shown in the second screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `neovim-gnome-terminal-wrapper` [Github project](https://github.com/fmoralesc/neovim-gnome-terminal-wrapper) which does exactly what I need.

[image: Screenshot showing active neovim launcher icon]